# How to get the type of a class that is being declared and returned form a function

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes a few dependency (as an object) for a class and then declares and returns the class.

See it in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

```
// makeWorker.ts ---------------
function makeWorker(someDependency: any) {
  return class Worker {
    print() {
      console.log("worker");
    }
  };
}

// useWorker.ts ----------------
const WorkerClass = makeWorker({
  /* some dependency here */
});
```

Now, I want to create instance of that class like the following example where I'm using **jest** to test some stuff.

```
let worker: typeof WorkerClass;

beforeEach(() => {
  worker = new Worker();
  worker.print(); // this line doesn't exist in my code. it's just for demonstration
});
```

But then I got the error

```
Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'Worker' but required in type 'typeof Worker'.
Property 'print' does not exist on type 'typeof Worker'.(2339)
```

### Edit

I know that, if we want to declare a variable as an instance of a certain class then we need to write `let var: TheClassName;`. But the reason I used `typeof WorkerClass` because if I use `let worker: WorkerClass;` then I get the following error.

```
'WorkerClass' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof WorkerClass'?(2749)
```

### End Edit

After working with it a little bit, I discovered that the following snippet doesn't raise any error.

```
const worker = new WorkerClass();
worker.print();
```

So I thought, may be I'm not getting the type of `WorkerClass` correctly and I tried the following but it didn't help. I got the same error again.

```
let worker: ReturnType<typeof makeWorker>;

worker = new worker();
worker.print();
```

Finally, I was browsing through the docs of Utility Types and randomly tried the utility type `InstanceType` on the `WorkerClass` and it worked on the first try!

```
let worker: InstanceType<typeof WorkerClass>;

worker = new WorkerClass();
worker.print();
```

Now my **question** is: why I can't use the `WorkerClass` in variable declaration and what the `InstanceType` is actually doing in the last example that it doesn't raise any error.

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Click into the `InstanceType`, right-click it, and click on "go to definition"

Comment: @Akxe I just did and found: `type InstanceType<T extends abstract new (...args: any) => any> = T extends abstract new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any`. But I don't really know much about `infer` and where is that `R` coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InstanceType` makes use of type inferration.  Basically, it allows you to take data from a given type that matches the given pattern.  This can only be used in conditional clauses.  A basic example of this is the following code:

```
type Foo = { hello: "world"; } extends { hello: infer Hello } ? Hello : never; // "world"
```

As you can see, we get the value of `hello` from the object by inferring the property.

Now, in the case of `InstanceType`, it uses type inferration on the constructor methods:

```
type InstanceType<T extends abstract new (...args: any) => any> = T extends abstract new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;
```

The `abstract new (...args: any) => any` is basically just the type for a constructor that has any arguments and returns a type of any.  Then, it infers the return type from the given constructor function using `infer R`.  I hope this helps explain how this works for you.

Comment: Hey __sno2__ thank you so much for your explanation of `InstanceType`. Could you kindly explain why the first and second (with the `ReturnType<typeof makeWorker`) snippets are raising that error?

Comment: `typeof Class` => The actual constructor you call to create the class, while `InstanceType<typeof Class>` => The type of an instance of the class. Clearly, a constructor of a class is not remotely the same as an instance of the class. As such there is an error.

Comment: @youdateme I understand that. I think I didn't explain question clearly. Kindly see the edit. My question is why I cannot use `let worker: WorkerClass`?

Comment: @h-sifat You can only use classes defined regularly in types.  `WorkerClass` is not a regular class definition, it is a constant that is a reference to a class.  Therefore, you must use the `typeof` to show that you want the expected type of the constant at that point in time.

Comment: Well, If that's the case then I've no more questions. Thanks for your answer.